# Asymmetric File encryption with Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, x509certificate, jce

I have a pfx file that contains public key and private key, I want to use these keys to encrypt and decrypt files locally on my machine.
That is my code:

```
public static void encryptFile(File file, PublicKey key,
        String transformation) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(transformation, "SunJCE");
    byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");

    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivspec);

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
            new File(file.getName() + "_enc")), c);

    copy(is, os);
}

public static void decryptFile(File encryptedFile, File decryptedFile,
        Key privateKey, String transformation) {
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(transformation, "SunJCE");

        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        byte[] keyb = privateKey.getEncoded();

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivspec);
        CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                encryptedFile), c);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);

        copy(is, os);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {

    try {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        while (true) {
            int r = is.read(buf);
            if (r == -1) {
                break;
            }
            os.write(buf, 0, r);
            total += r;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it like that:

```
            CertificateHandler.encryptFile(new File("test.pdf"), pb, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        CertificateHandler.decryptFile(new File("test.pdf_enc"), new File("test.enc.pdf"), pk, "AES/CBC/NoPadding");
```

But I get this error:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 294 bytes
```

I used Unlimited JCE Policy but nothing changed. And when I try to use digested keys it doesn't work I think because the key it cutted and no more valid

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the "transform" parameter you use? Though seems you're missing some important concepts m writing an answer..

Comment: @gusto2 I use  "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do the encryption right, you're missing some details.

AES is a symmetric cipher taking a **key size of 128, 192 or 256 bits**.   You cannot just use an RSA private key with any encryption scheme.

For using RSA keys just search the net, for example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Security/RSAencryptdecryptfunctionRSAECBPKCS1Padding.htm

Usually how encryption of longer content (files) is done:

(please note there are multiple options or modes, what I write here is a simple suggestion)

Encryption:

1. generate a random AES key (128bit will do) and nonce (IV) - for IV do not use the fixed vector as it is in your code
2. use RSA to encrypt the generated key (e.g. RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding)
3. compute digest (hash) of the content (sha-256)
4. to the output stream write the encrypted AES key, IV, digest and  encrypted content (AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding).

Decryption

1. read the AES key, nonce and digest from the stream
2. decrypt the key with your RSA private key
3. read the and decrypt the content
4. compute digest of the decrypted content and compare it with the already read hash, fail if they do not match

It seems complicated, but skipping any of these steps may (and often will) result in encryption being broken. Even these steps need to have some properties (fixed execution time, etc, but for start you should be ok).